# ElasticSearch-Rails multi_match fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

My model associations:

```
class CertificatePeriod < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certificate_orders
  has_many :order_transactions, through: :certificate_orders
end

class CertificateOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :certificate_period
  has_one :order_transaction
end

class OrderTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :certificate_order
end
```

In OrderTransaction model:

```
class OrderTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    self.as_json(only: [:id, cardholdername, :userid],
    include: {certificate_order: {include: {user: {only: [:first_name, :last_name], methods: :full_name}}}})
  end
end
```

Example response of this indexed:

```
{"id"=>7235,
 "cardholdername"=>"NUR SARUHAN",
 "userid"=>"zzzyyyxxxx",
 "certificate_order"=>
  {"id"=>292,
   "user_id"=>13186,
   "certificate_enrollment_id"=>768,
   "slug"=>"eafe0be5-0b1f-4e4f-8929-d3f9330a4a86f7c25b1199dcd5",
   "created_at"=>Mon, 11 Apr 2016 18:30:58 EEST +03:00,
   "updated_at"=>Mon, 11 Apr 2016 18:30:58 EEST +03:00,
   "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Nur", "last_name"=>"SARUHAN", "full_name"=>"NUR SARUHAN"}}}
```

I have used search query something like this:

```
query: {
  bool: {
    must: [
      {ids: {values: @certificate_period.order_transactions.pluck(:id)}},
      {bool: {
        should: [
          {multi_match: {query: params[:q], fields: ['cardholdername', 'certificate_order.user.first_name']}}
        ]
      }}
    ]
  }
}).records.to_a
```

My question is:

Actually this search query has worked but the following lines are returned exactly same records.

```
{multi_match: {query: params[:q], fields: ['cardholdername', 'certificate_order.user.first_name']}}
```

and

```
{multi_match: {query: params[:q], fields: ['cardholdername']}}
```

It is returned an empty array if I just use `certificate_order.user.first_name` as parameter in multi_match fields. So there is no effect of `certificate_order.user.first_name`. I have googled for 3 days but I haven't found right answer. What should I do to get the value of the `certificate_order.user.first_name` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) gem. You can merge different attributes between models in your search query to help change the scope of your search. It's a great gem overall.